# Server error: if (User.IsInRole("Administrators"))

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC 4 internet application I can't use this:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
```

It result in this error:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The >server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is >configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating >Server/Instance Specified)

This has been bothering me for quite a long time any help is REALLY appreciated.

Here is the stack trace:

```
    [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)]
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) +5296071
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) +558
   System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover) +5308555
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover) +145
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout) +920
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance) +307
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions) +434
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +5311099
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +37
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +558
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +67
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1052
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +78
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +167
   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +143
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry) +83
   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +96
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHolder.Open(HttpContext context, Boolean revertImpersonate) +88
   System.Web.DataAccess.SqlConnectionHelper.GetConnection(String connectionString, Boolean revertImpersonation) +239
   System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) +762
   WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider.GetRolesForUser(String username) +53
   System.Web.Security.RolePrincipal.IsInRole(String role) +9461104
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in e:\HR\Vorönn 2013\VERK\Bordspil\Bordspil\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:23
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +97
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +62
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +76
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +295
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +89
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629296
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

EDIT: It only results in this error when I auto login.

Comment: What part of the error message don't you understand?

Comment: The part where I fix it...
But seriously, I've been trying to get this to work for hours but nothing has happened.

Comment: We had these kind of troubles and solved them, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708202/error-running-mvc4-on-azure

Answer (score 8):

In MVC `User.IsInRole` or similar Authorization Methods are trying to use SimpleMembership provider by default.

If you are using a custom authorization you need to add the below code to your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="RoleManager" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

If you are using SimpleMembership make sure its databases are initialized.

Answer (score 2):

This problem means that you can't connect to your database.

You should check your connectionstring and see whether you really have access to the database.

Note: It's possible that the connectionstring is correct and your database is available but that you have a network-related problem (port is not opened for example)

There's a possibility that you're using two different conncetion string (one for your normal data objects and one for the membership). You should check the following things:

- (Supposing you're using SimpleMembership): Under the folder `filters` there's a class called `InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute`. Locate the call to `WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection`. The first parameter to that method is the name of the connectionstring it will look up in the `web.config`. Make sure this is the correct name
- Look in your `web.config` and make sure that the connection string is correct (for the simplemembership provider)

Comment: I'm connected to the database itself (just using a local one) and can connect to things in there, just not this exact thing.

Comment: Make sure you're using the same connection string for the membership database

Comment: That's the thing, it's all 1 database.

Comment: Although it's all in one database, it's possible that you're using a different connection string for your normal db and the membership. I've edited my answer for more information

Comment: In the Filter it is: "DefaultConnection"
In the web.config:
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Hopur5-20130509151228;Integrated security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Hopur5-20130509151228.mdf"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="aspnet_Hopur5_20130509151228ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Hopur5-20130509151228.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Hopur5-20130509151228;Integrated Security=True"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: So 2 connectionstrings in the web.config

Comment: OK, so remove the entry that is used in the filter and change the name in the filter to the one you are using for the rest of your application

Comment: Still the same... I'm lost.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29697/discussion-between-kenneth-and-zanii)

Comment: I would really like that, but I'm too tired.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: OK, cool, I was about to quit as well. Hope you find a solution!

Answer (score 0):

We had the same kind of problems and solved them. Check the following link

[Error running MVC4 on Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16708202/error-running-mvc4-on-azure)

The idea is to ensure the connection is created for every session started (so even after a timeout, where we had troubles as MVC uses a non existing connection).